# What is the most efficient algorithm for online Non- negative Matrix Factorization (NMF)?

Tags: machine-learning, matrix-decomposition, non-negative-matrix-factorization

What is the most efficient algorithm for online Non- negative Matrix Factorization (NMF) in recent study?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to articulate your question more clearly, especially with regard to the particular non-negative matrix factorization you have in mind. You might be more likely to get insightful responses on the 
Computational Science board at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ .So you might want to request that your question be moved there.